# MAP in profile view of approach plate

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, instrument-procedures, missed-approach

I understand that the start of the dotted arrow on the profile view of an approach plate shows the MAP for the precision approach on a plate if the plate combines more than 1 (for example, a plate depicting an ILS or LOC approach). Even though an LPV approach is not technically a precision approach, the beginning of the dotted arrow would indicate the MAP for an LPV as well. Can someone cite me a reference document (the AIM, Instrument Flying Handbook, Terminal Procedures Supplemental, ect..) to verify this? I have been looking and I can't seem to find one.

Thank you

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is IAC 4, section 3.4.5.6.

The longer answer is twofold. First, an LPV approach is considered “non-precision” because it doesn’t meet the ICAO definition of precision. However, for the purposes of charting, precision and non-precision refer to whether a procedure has vertical guidance (and a Decision Altitude vs a Minimum Descent Altitude). Additionally, IAC 4 sections 3.4.5.9 and 3.4.5.11 include RNAV as a type of precision approach. An approach with LPV minima is considered precision.

Second, the Interagency Air Committee is responsible for developing the charting standards for the US government. In the specifications related to instrument approach procedures, the following is what answers your question:

“3.4.5.6 Procedure Track

A profile view of the procedure track shall be shown using an 8 weight (.020") line. The approach track shall begin toward the top of the primary facility line, unless otherwise dictated by the procedure, and shall descend to .10" above the underline, where the final approach ends and the missed approach begins.

On non-precision only approach procedures, the approach track will begin at the point specified on the procedure source document and descend to the MDA or VDP, thence horizontally to the missed approach point. The segment shall typically be 0.2" in length but length may vary due to the layout of the profile components.”

With that in mind, consider how that is aligned with the legend.
[image]